# Copy a variable range in excel with VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am a little confused. I created a button with a macro that copy a selection of cells from another sheet `s` in my actual sheet `s0` (both `s` and `s0` are string variables)

```
Sheets(s0).Range("D56:K80").Value = Sheets(s).Range("L2:S26").Value
```

and all works. But If I try to write something more flexible, such as a range that can vary the starting row

```
x = Cells(2, 4).Value 'x is a number defined by user
Sheets(s0).Range(Cells(56, 4), Cells(80, 11)).Value = Sheets(s).Range(Cells(2 + x, 2), Cells(26 + x, 9)).Value
```

nothing works and 1004 error appears. What is the problem?
What am I doing wrong?

The situation does not change if I compute the sums out of the Cells command.
But something like

```
Sheets(s).Cells(r, c) = x
```

works when I change the value of a single cell with variabiles values of r and c. (x, r and c are always integer)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must qualify all ranges references up to worksheet object:

```
Sheets(s0).Range(Sheets(s0).Cells(56, 4), Sheets(s0).Cells(80, 11)).Value = Sheets(s).Range(Sheets(s).Cells(2 + x, 2), Sheets(s).Cells(26 + x, 9)).Value
```

the use of `With-End With` syntax can relieve the typing burden a little

```
With Sheets(s)
    Sheets(s0).Range(Sheets(s0).Cells(56, 4), Sheets(s0).Cells(80, 11)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2 + x, 2), .Cells(26 + x, 9)).Value
End With
```

while if you know *for sure* that "s0" is the *active* sheet (i.e. the one to which all unqualified worksheet reference default) while the macro runs then you can omit its qualification:

```
With Sheets(s)
    Range(Cells(56, 4), Cells(80, 11)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2 + x, 2), .Cells(26 + x, 9)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations! I also found alternative solution that is `Sheets(s0).Range("D56:K80").Value = Sheets(s).Range("B2:I26").Offset(x, 0).Value` (I found solutions by myself always "after" posting the question!) but thanks to you I understand my error.